# Can't add torrent file to uTorrent server

Tags: server, bittorrent, utorrent

So I downloaded and insalled uTorrent on my Ubuntu seed box which is just a small computer I would like to use as a NAS, to download movies and stuff. Anyway, when I try to add a torrent file through the web GUI, nothing happens. I tried to add the torrent URL, but that didn't work eiter. So why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I managed to fix it! It's actually a very easy fix: download Deluge and uninstall uTorrent and that's it! Hope it helped someone!